# Fetching Values from Services

Tags: ios, web-services

I am new in Service Responses.i am not able to separate `"First Class"` and `"Second Class"`
into a separate array.also from this response i need first class as an array and second class as an array. and in first class i need to fetch `class_id` and `class_name` as a string.it will continue upto `fifteen classes`.how can i identify whether the response is `first class` or `second class` or someother class ? Struggling lot for a long. Thanks in Advance.

```
Response :{
"First Class" =     (
            {
        "class_id" = 2;
        "class_name" = "Art";
            },{
        "class_id" = 2;
        "class_name" = "Medical";
            }
        );
   "Second Class" =   (
            {
        "class_id" = 3;
        "class_name" = "Swim";
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this.

As per your code, your service response is `dictionary`.
Note: assume `responseDictionary` your service Response.

If your response has 'n' number of classes,then separate each class like this

```
//get individual classes like this

for(int i=0;i<[[responseDictionary allKeys]count];i++)
{
    NSArray *class = [responseDictionary objectForKey:[[responseDictionary allKeys]objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

and then

```
for(NSDictionary *individualDict in individualClassArray)
{
    NSString *classID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[individualDict objectForKey:@"class_id"]];
    NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[individualDict objectForKey:@"class_name"]];
    NSLog(@"class id %@",classID);
    NSLog(@"class name %@", className);
}
```

Comment: i am getting [[responseDictionary allKeys]count] as 1.but there are 3.how can i solve this ?

Comment: sorry.got it.i have solved that count issue.now its working fine.thanks

Answer (score 1):

As your code contains dictionary inside array and than again dictionary so try like this:-

```
NSArray *firstClass=[yourDictArray objectAtIndex:0];

for (NSDictionary *dc in firstClass)
{
    NSString *str=[dc objectForKey:@"key"];
}

NSArray *secondClass=[yourDictArray objectAtIndex:1];

for (NSDictionary *dc1 in firstClass)
{
    NSString *str1=[dc1 objectForKey:@"key"];
}
```

Comment: if the response has 4 classes ? how can i identify ?

Comment: U can get number of class by yourDictArray.count

Comment: This is for understanding purpose you can iterate the loop no matters if you have 100 classes. Let me know if you have any issue??

Comment: @hussain Shabbir - i am not able to fetch [[responseDictionary allKeys]count] correctly.can you help me in this ?

Comment: sorry.got it.i have solved that count issue.now its working fine.thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure how you tried but try like this execute for loop and then write the condition like this for(i=0; i<[responseDictionary allKeys]count];i++) after this include above code